# I'm a newbie in C++,and I 'm now stuck in pointer

Tags: c++

I create a function to display the element of an array with position shift to right 3,In case the element overload if will shift to the left, I used pointer to pass by value.The code almost worked but it display 0 instead of input elements. Can somebody show me why, pls!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int * sort (const int * const ,int );
void display_origin_order(const int * const ,int );
int * sort(const int * const array,int size)
{
    for (int i;i<size;++i)
     {
         if(i+3<size||i+3==size)
         {
          cout<<*(array+i+3)<<" ";
         }
         if (i+3>size)
         {
          cout<<*(array+i-2)<<" ";
         }
     }
     return 0;
    cout<<endl;
}
void display_origin_order(const int * const array,int size)
{
    for (int i;i<size;++i)
     {
      cout<<array[i]<<" ";
     }
    cout<<endl;
}
int main ()
{
    int * first_array{nullptr};
    int size{0};
    first_array = new int [size];
    int init_value{0};
    cout<<"Please enter the size of the array \n";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"Now its elements \n";
    for (int i;i<size;++i)
    {
        cout<<"input variable \n";
        cin>>init_value;
        first_array[i] = init_value;
    }
    cout<<"The array's elements in origin order are : ";
    display_origin_order(first_array,size);
    cout<<"The array's elements in required order are: ";
    sort (first_array,size);
    delete [] first_array;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has multiple issues. Start from the top of `main`: `int size{0}; first_array = new int [size];`: How large will the array be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your bound check is actually out of bound. The array index starts from `0`, and ends in `size-1`, and if you want to shift the element, you should substract `size`, not `2`. In addition, you did not initialized `i` in the `for` loops in your program, which leads to undefined behavior. Here's my modification:

```
int * sort(const int * const array,int size)
{
    for (int i=0;i<size;++i)
     {
         if(i+3<size)
         {
          cout<<*(array+i+3)<<" ";
         }
         else
         {
          cout<<*(array+i+3-size)<<" ";
         }
     }
     return 0;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Addition : `sort` is not a proper name for this function. I suggest the name `display_shift` to reduce the reader's confusion.

EDIT: As @user17732522 pointed out, main function also has some bugs. you initialized the `first_array` by `new int[size]`, when the `size` is 0. you have to initialize the `first_array` after getting the `size` like this:

```
int main ()
{
    int * first_array{nullptr};
    int size{0};
    int init_value{0};
    cout<<"Please enter the size of the array \n";
    cin>>size;
    first_array = new int [size];        // initialize the first_array AFTER you get its size...
    cout<<"Now its elements \n";
    for (int i=0;i<size;++i) // You forgot the initialization here, too!
    {
    // rest is same...
    }
}
```

Addition 2 : When you trying to shift the elements, there is more simpler, safer way to do this, using the operator `%`:

```
void display_shift(const int * const array,int size)
{
    for (int i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        cout<<*(array+(i+3)%size)<<" ";
    }
}
```

That's because when the `size` is so small that `i+3` is more than twice the `size`, you actually have subtract `2*size`, and the program will be more complicated. modulo operator(`%`) reduces those complication, and you do not have to check bound when using this operator!

Comment: That's not the only thing that's wrong with the code.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh, Thank you for the letting me knnow additional bugs, I will modify it right now..

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not prompting for input is because you do not initialize `i` in your for loops. Your for loops currently are `for (int i; i < size; ++i)`, but should be `for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)`. If you do not initialize `i`, then its value is undefined, and it may start with any value which causes the loop to happen any number of times (or no times at all).

Comment: That's not the only issue with the code.

Comment: Yes that's very true. This will get you to at least get input, but as said before, there are many other problems to fix. Updated to specify that.